# How to grep with expansion of curly braces?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a list of files that have the nomenclature `yyyyMMdd`. I would like to get the lsit of the files excluding a few dates. To do so I use the following command

```
$ ls | grep -ve 202003{04,11,23}
grep: 20200311: Is a directory
grep: 20200323: Is a directory
```

The command only works if I expand out the curly brace manually, spacing the option `-e` inbetween, i.e.

```
ls | grep -v -e 20200304 -e 20200311 -e 20200323
```

What would be a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't to this with shell expansion as you want to do because it will replace your single argument with multiple separate arguments (if and only if there are files or directories that match the pattern - if there is no match other undesired things can happen). However, the argument to `grep` is a regular expression. With extended regular expressions (the `-E` flag) you can do this.

```
$ ls | grep -vEe "202003(04|11|23)"
```

Do note, you don't need `-e` for a single search parameter, so

```
$ ls | grep -vE "202003(04|11|23)"
```

also works.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do extended regex always require double quotation marks?

Comment: Quote protect you from the shell trying to interpret special characters. In this case, without quotes both the `(` and `|` characters would be interpreted by the shell as special and would not end up being passed to `grep` at all (try it and see). You are (nearly) always safer just quoting arguments passed to scripts to make sure the shell does not interpret in a special way.

Comment: But I thought double quotation marks would expand any regex due to special characters?

Comment: No, you are very mistaken about what is happening. You are passing a pattern to match to `grep`. `grep` then *internally* matches this pattern against the strings given to it. You want the pattern to be passed to `grep` without being altered in any way by the shell. Without quotes, the shell may modify the argument. For example, if your pattern were "20*" to match a `2` followed by 0 or more `0`, and you did not quote it, the shell would expand the `*` character *before* `grep` even gets a chance to see it. With quotes it's passed to `grep` as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You may need this: `ls | grep -vP "202003(04|11|23)"`

If `-P` doesn't work, try replace it with `-E`.